# solve equation of form $x = a - (b - x)^c$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Is there a general solution (for $x$) to an equation of the form $x = a - (b - x)^c$ ?  If there is no general solution, please suggest a strategy for getting a numerical answer.  In the case I care about immediately, two different computer algebra systems got as far as $x = 50\,000 - (100 - x)^{500\,000}$ and then got stuck when asked for a numeric answer.

Comment: If you let $b-x=y$, you get a nicer equation $$b - a = y - {y^c}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming $a,b,x$ are reals and $c$ is an integer, your equation becomes

$$ a-(b-x)^c-x = 0$$

which can be converted to

$$a-x-\sum_{i=0}^c \begin{pmatrix} c \\ i \end{pmatrix} b^ix^{c-i} = 0$$

using the binomial theorem.

For $c > 4$, there is no *general* solution for this polynomial by the Abel-Ruffini theorem. However, it may be possible that for certain specific conditions on $a, b \in \Bbb R$ that allow it to be solved.

Answer (score 1):

With *Mathematica*

```
FindRoot[50000 - (100 - x)^500000 == x, {x, 99}, AccuracyGoal -> 20, 
WorkingPrecision -> 50]
```

I get x = 98.999978364173304772436016428458876920765894232268
You can get more accurate values by increasing the WorkingPrecision.
You can use Newton's Method with something like this.

Answer (score 0):

If such an x exists it will be between 98 and 99, and by between them I mean it's going to be very close to 99.

Using maple I could maybe get close just by messing around with it.  If such an x exists it is between x = 98.9999783650000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001 and x = 98.9999783650000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

The fact that maple chokes on it tells me that an x likely does not exist.  I used this expression to look for it:
limit(ln(50000-x)/ln(100-x), x = 98.9999783650000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000, left)

This gives the answer: 4.999035752*10^5

and limit(ln(50000-x)/ln(100-x), x = 98.9999783650000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001, left)

which provides an answer of: 5.001346887*10^5

Edit: I've now tried it in maple and wolfram alpha, and managed to exceed computation time on wolfram alpha for non pro members, and I managed to hang my laptop with maple, as it appears that 4GB of memory wasn't enough.

Comment: These CAS libraries likely do not stock the requisite solvers to compute the solution to that extreme precision, I would imagine.